# Trigonometry identity proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can anybody prove the following? 
$$\frac{\sin^3 a- \cos^3 a}{\sin a- \cos a}= 1 + \sin a \ \cos a.$$

Thanks.

Comment: Think about $a^3-b^3=(a-b)\times \cdots ??$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: $x^3 - y^3 = (x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2)$